# as2 video resume

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How can I do resume video.

```
general.video_button.onRelease = function(){
    if (general.stop_button._visible == false){
        general.video.resume();
    }
    general.video.play(0);
    general.video_button._visible = false;
    general.stop_button._visible = true;
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Video.pause() was previously called, playback begins from the current position. If Video.stop() was previously called, playback begins from the first frame.

```
general.video_button.onRelease = function(){
    if (general.stop_button._visible == false){
        general.video.resume();
        general.video_button._visible = true;
        general.stop_button._visible = false;
        return;
    }
    general.video.pause();
    general.video_button._visible = false;
    general.stop_button._visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But not worked. When I  clear return; code is run. But not resume.

Comment: Please try now with the pause method.